# Trigger Javascript Actions when PHP form successfully sends

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am trying to get a message box to display a message based on if the form successfully submitted. I am not sure why but when I click the submit button on the form I am redirected to a blank white page.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php"> <!-- removed the PHP file name to post to itself -->
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="65" name="message"placeholder="Message"></textarea><br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Let's Get In Touch">
</form>

<div id="confirmationBox">
    <p id="confirmationMessage">Your message has been sent!</p>
    <button>OK</button>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: Portfolio Website'; 
    $to = 'kyle.a.binger@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message From Personal Site';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {

          /*echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#submit").val("Message Submitted!");
          </script>';*/

           echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
           echo 'var a = document.getElementById("confirmationMessage");';
           echo 'a.innerHTML = "Message Sent!"';
           echo '</script>';

        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is the live site as it stands now
[Portfolio Site- Work In Progress](http://kylebinger.com)

Comment: View the source of the white page. What do you see there?

Comment: @JayBlanchard i thought it was just directing me to a blank HTML page but suprisingly the javascript it was suppose to execute is contained in the head of this blank page in a script tag

Comment: That's what I thought. Is the console reporting any errors?

Comment: @JayBlanchard there seems to be one error in the console

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

But i think this is because the html is blank so it can't find the element its looking for

Comment: Your JS code is referring to confirmationMessage element but you don't create any. Try to echo '<div id="confirmationMessage"></div>'; before you output JS.

Comment: @KostyaShkryob I have created that element in my index.html file. I guess what I'm trying to accomplish is have the form submit, stay on my html page and then execute the JavaScript code to change the confirmationMessage

Comment: If that is what you want to do you're going to have to use AJAX

Comment: I guess Ill have to dive into that and learn it haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your front and back-end are really tightly-coupled. It would make your life a lot easier to decouple your setup.

- Just grab the form data and POST it to the back using ajax
- Return a response-code and some JSON based on weather your email succeeds or not
- Show your success message in the .done callback, or extend that further to show an error message using the .fail callback

The reason it goes to blank page is because your form POST is firing and re-directing to contact.php. In order to prevent that, you need to call .preventDefault() on the form's submit event.

```
$("form").on( "submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "contact.php",
      data: $(this).serialize()
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      // Show your success message here
    })
   .fail(function(error) {
     // Show your error message here
   })
})
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

---

for testing purpose, you can add a else action in your PHP code :

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {

      /*echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#submit").val("Message Submitted!");
      </script>';*/

       echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
       echo 'var a = document.getElementById("confirmationMessage");';
       echo 'a.innerHTML = "Message Sent!"';
       echo '</script>';

    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    }
} else {
    echo "the request was : " . $_POST['submit'];
}
```

But i think it would be better to use an AJAX request , so you stay on the original page and show/hide the div with the id "confirmationMessage"

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the submit button, you get redirected to the PHP file, the HTML file with the form is "forgotten". So if the mail is sent, the browser gets your java-script, but nothing else. (The browser redirects you to the file specified in the form tag, after submitting the browser only has the code from the PHP file, which only sends the java-script, but no HTML/Text to display)

Comment: Thanks your answer makes sense to me logically, but how do i get the form to submit while staying on my index.html page and executing the JavaScript actions I want to execute?

Comment: @KyleBing You can do that through ajax, look at the answer of Graham T.